# i18n concept mapping of translation strings

Tags: javascript, string, dictionary, internationalization, translation

I am an intern working at an internet company on a Javascript library. My employer ask me to "think about" how do we map **translation strings from typically external files to templates**

To be honest, I don't know what does that mean. Can someone point me to the right resources? Better Still, can someone provide me with a scenario to explain the sentence and also propose an approach to solve that?

Comment: I don't know what it means either. Maybe you should ask your employer to clarify.

Comment: @Pointy I thought it was something obvious. In that case, I ll ask him for clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's more of a server side issue, and less of a JavaScript issue. As far as "map translation strings from typically external files to templates", they're most likely talking about [gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/) like functionality.

For example, in PHP there is the [gettext](http://us.php.net/gettext) series of functions. They use "external files" known as `.po` files to provide translations. Translations are mapped depending on the user's chosen locale by using the `gettext()` function (usually abbreviated as `_()`). JavaScript doesn't really have this functionality, nor in my opinion should it.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a javascript i18n (for string translation only) module that simply does something similar to gettext, but it is for javascript. Perhaps you could take a look at it : 
http://www.zomeoff.com/jsin/